# Activerecord: How to add functionality that responds to the saving or updating event?

Tags: activerecord

here's the **Activities** model

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :week, :day, :bcalor, :bicycl, :ccalor, :foodid, :jog, 
                  :lunges, :pushups, :situps, :squats
end
```

I'd like to add functionality, such as, after I save or update a activity, I be able to update the summary all the acitities. In .NET we have stuff like **OnModelUpdating** and **OnModelUpdated**. How do I accomplish the samething using activerecord?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails, they are called callbacks. Here you go: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html